# Nine patch image isn't rendering correctly

Tags: android

I am trying to learn nine patch images in android.I want to create message bubble.But it isn't rendering correctly.

I want something like this:

[image]

But result:

[image]

This is my nine patch image:

[image]

What is wrong with my image ?

Comment: you might want to try using this tool since you didnt do it right http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 1):

You file must be saved as `filename.9.png` to be correctly recognized as 9-patch image. It looks like yours is just `filename.png`

Comment: @Okan If so,  rebuild your project from the scratch